# Need to modify content of Lookuphoverdetail popup in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

Actually i have achieved to show the contact detail with Lookupoverdetail popup on my visualforce page. It shows default values as Contact Name, Account Name and Email.

Here i want to add/remove somehow contact detail.

Anyone help me to do that.[image: Please see my image]

Comment: "LookupHoverDetail" is actually a "Mini Page Layout"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These popups make use of the "Mini Page Layout". You will see a link to this by using Setup ->  Contacts -> Page Layouts and editing a page layout. The "Mini Page Layout" link is in the title bar of the WYSIWYG layout editor. You can add and remove (most) fields and change the order of the fields.

[image: Mini Page Layout link]